# Power an 8-channel relay without drawing power from the RPi

Tags: gpio, power

I've recently acquired an 8-channel relay from China. I've been reading and watching a lot about how to connect them to the RPi. For now I've only tried it out on an old RPi Model B (I didn't want to fry my new Pi), and it seemed to work great.

However, from what I've been gathering online, the best practice is to connect the relay to external power, so it doesn't draw too much from the RPi, but also so I can use the 5 V and 3.3 V for different purposes. My question is now, how would I go about doing this, and is it in fact the best practice?

The relay I've purchased looks like this:

[image: RPi Relay]

and I've bought it from this page, which contains some (quite limited) documentation of the product:

[AliExpress - 5v 8-channel Relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5V-Eight-8-Channel-Relay-Module-With-optocoupler-For-PIC-AVR-DSP-ARM-FOR-Arduino/2038553717.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.6w8lof)

I hope some of you accomplished makers can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each relay uses ~0.3W when closed (NC). That's ~2.4W, so you need a power supply of at least 5V/500mA, but more is better, up to 1A. You may need to power other stuff. Use a phone charger with a stripped USB cable.

Connect positive lead of power supply to VCC, and negative to GND on relay.

Use common ground, i.e. connect the Pi's GND to the power supply's GND. Do it on the relay board. You can also shift a jumper to avoid needing this. Since this board is 5V logic, use a MOSFET/BJT to turn on each relay, each using 5V on C-E or D-S, and 3V on B/G. Or use a levelshifter. It will take you 30 minutes to solder a perfboard with 8 switchers, and several days to get a hold of a level shifter (if you don't have one), so that's up to you.

The board has optocouplers and diodes, so you don't need to worry about flyback. 
Example: Connect 5V signal to positive terminal of relay (S+) and from relay GND, connect to DRAIN of a 2N7000 N-MOSFET. Wire SOURCE to GND. An N- MOSFET likes a 4K7 pull-down resistor, but a BJT (like the venerable BC239 NPN) doesn't need this. For that you need a 1K resistor to BASE. Use what you have.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far, I'm not sure I quite understand how to connect everything. Do you have an example schematic?

Comment: @AndreasVoss No, but words are just as good. Get a pen and draw it, it will be easier for you.

Comment: It's a real pretty relay, congratulations ;)

Comment: Have you figured it out now?

Comment: @Fusseldieb I found him, he's mine ;)

Comment: Oh, okay. I was about to make a drawing and upload it, but I think I don't need to anymore...

Comment: @Fusseldieb By all means, make a drawing. I was of course not calling dibs on Andreas Voss. He likes drawings.

Comment: It's an awful drawing, but I think you get the point (I am in hurry): https://s13.postimg.org/xxj1sncd3/relaispins.jpg (The dotted line you connect, if you want both to run of the same power source (Then you can  unplug the USB powering the Pi). If you need to know which pins on the Pi are GPIO, just google: "Raspberry 3 GPIO Pinout" or similar.

Comment: I'll need to buy a few more components to get this setup going, but I think I'm good to go, thanks for your support!

Comment: @AndreasVoss Because you are a german, you are disciplined and tough. Godspeed! (Please don't buy levelshifter, it is a very disappointing little IC, and I feel bad for telling you about it)

Comment: @Fusseldieb What about resistors? Do you know that these pins draw less than or equal to 8mA, and that the optocouplers turn fully on at 3.3V?

Comment: @user2497 I have to disappoint you, I am not German although I understand the confusion with my name. I am actually Danish. Anyhow I'll listen to your advice and forget all about levelshifters.

Comment: @AndreasVoss Well, you'll have to settle for potatoes and Dansk Folkeparti then. Please post a pic of the board you make.

Comment: @user2497 You clearly know your countries! I'll connect everything I have on hand, and draw the rest tomorrow afternoon, then when I get the last components I'll post another picture.

Comment: @AndreasVoss Yeah, the 3.3V from the Pi switches the Relais without problems.